# A quesyion about Function space

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

A "function space" is simply a set of functions from a given set to another given set. So my understanding is $
f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text { with }f_{n}(x)=x^{n}, n=0,1,2
$ is a function space  with only 3 elements. But using "space" is wierd since this is not closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Also what's the basis of this space? Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 'vector  space' is used for sets closed under addition and scalar multiplication. But 'space' does not mean 'vector space. We talk about metric spaces, topological spaces, etc which are not vector spaces.

However, the term 'functions space' is often used for vector spaces of functions.